# How do I call an ArrayAdapter object's function from my main activity?

Tags: android, function, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an object called Score that I'm using in an ArrayAdapter. How do I call the functions that are defined within it? Below is my main activity including the line I'm trying to fix.

```
public class ScoreList extends Activity {

    private ListView listViewScore;
    private Context ctx;

    ArrayList<Integer> allScoreChange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> allScore = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score_list);
        ctx = this;
        final List<Score> listScore = new ArrayList<Score>();
        listScore.add(new Score("Player A", "0", "0"));
        listScore.add(new Score("Player B", "0", "0"));
        listScore.add(new Score("Player C", "0", "0"));

        for(int i = 0; i < listScore.size(); i++)
        {
            allScoreChange.set(i,0);
            allScore.set(i,listScore.getScoreTotal(i)); // this is the line I'm working on
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the Score object itself with the function.

```
public class Score {

    private String name;
    private String scoreChange;
    private String scoreTotal;

    public Score(String name, String scoreChange, String scoreTotal) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.scoreChange = scoreChange;
        this.scoreTotal = scoreTotal;
    }

    public String getScoreTotal() {
        return scoreTotal;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> allScore.set(i,listScore.getScoreTotal(i)); // this is the line I'm working on
> ```

Use the List's `get()` method:

```
allScore.set(i, listScore.get(i).getScoreTotal());
```

(To be technical, `listScore` is a List not an ArrayAdapter.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning and am accessing Score via an adapter so I got my wording mixed up.